# Ubuntu 14.04: Software updater running automaticly?

Tags: wireless, update-manager

This morning when I woke up the software updater wanted me to reboot and also the wireless connection was down (went down sometime during the night). How can this happen? I seem to remember that I rebooted after the last update I performed. And the setting is “Display immediately”, i.e. automatic download and install is not enabled. Can someone explain how this can happen? What logs can I look at to find out more?